# ruby: util.c:95: tds_set_state: Assertion `tds->state < (sizeof(state_names)/sizeof(state_names[0]))' failed. Aborted

Tags: ruby, tiny-tds

I get the following error when I read more than 100 message at consumer side. I publish messages to RabbitMQ and have run a consumer to read from RabbitMQ it breaks when find more than 100 or sometimes 90's messages the error is given below

```
ruby: util.c:95: tds_set_state: Assertion `tds->state < (sizeof(state_names)/sizeof(state_names[0]))' failed. Aborted
```

Ok and thanks. Let me Explain the problem. See I have a publisher written in .Net that pushes messages to RabbitMQ(Open source Q) then I have a consumer That reads from that Queue. It reads fine when there are less than 100 messages in a minute but when the amount exceeds it fires the error and the app is terminated with the above error i provided

Comment: While it's helpful to show us the error, there is nothing we can do to help you without a minimized code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok and thanks. Let me Explain the problem. See I have a publisher written in .Net that pushes messages to RabbitMQ(Open source Q) then I have a consumer That reads from that Queue. It reads fine when there are less than 100 messages in a minute but when the amount exceeds it fires the error and the app is terminated with the above error i provided

Comment: Now, put that into the question by editing it, don't comment on the question.